# How can I write a function to detect whether a object exists in R and if it doesn't, read in a file by that name?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that can either be executed interactively using objects/data loaded in R, or as a script that will read in a file with the name of the provided argument if it doesn't exist. I'm pretty close, but I guess there's some problem with the enviroments maybe; the function is acting like there's a ghost variable defined in the function that I can't change.

Here's what I have so far:

```
test<- function(hello) {
  bye <- (as.character(substitute(hello)))
  if(!exists(bye)) {
    assign(bye, as.data.frame(read_table2(bye,col_names = FALSE)),envir= .GlobalEnv)
    if (class(hello[[1]][[1]]) == "character") {
      do.call(`rm`,list(as.character(substitute(hello)),inherits=TRUE),envir=.GlobalEnv)
      assign(bye, as.data.frame(read_table2(bye,col_names = TRUE)),envir= .GlobalEnv)
      print(sys.frame(which=0))
      print(sys.parents())
      #assign(as.character(substitute(hello)),get(bye, pos=".GlobalEnv"))
    }
  }
  #assign(as.character(substitute(hello)),get(bye))
  print(as.character(substitute(hello)))
  print(class(hello))
  print(class("hello"))
  print(hello)
  print(sys.frame(which=0))
}
test(testdata.csv)
print(testdata.csv)
```

The commented lines are some of the things I've tried that don't change anything. All of the `print`s are included as diagnostics, and should have the same values whether the object was preloaded or just read in. The idea of the second `if` statement is that the first time I've assumed that the file won't have column names, and so I check it for characters and if there are try to reload it with column names. I'm pretty sure What I have isn't the most efficent way to do this so any ideas on improving it in general are welcome, but it all seems to work except when `testdata.csv` has column names. When it prints the data (`print(hello)`) at the end there still aren't coumn names, even though the variable `testdata.csv` is visible in the global environment afterwards *with* the column names.

Here's the output of the above to illustrate:

```
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
[1] 0
[1] "testdata.csv"
[1] "data.frame"
[1] "character"
   X1 X2
1   a  b
2   1  1
3   2  1
4   3  1
5   4  1
6   5  1
7   6  2
8   7  2
9   8  3
10  9  4
11 10  5
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

   a b
1   1 1
2   2 1
3   3 1
4   4 1
5   5 1
6   6 2
7   7 2
8   8 3
9   9 4
10 10 5
```

I know this was sort of long so to clarify, how can I get `hello` in the code above to point to the global `testdata.csv` that is read in during the function? I have no clue why it doesn't already, but it's not. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, both `exists` and `assign` take an argument `envir=`, and it is relevant. While I generally dislike the use of `assign` in most cases, I think it can be done safely using `parent.frame()` so that this is safe and doesn't work too far out of data-scope.

```r
getit <- function(x, envir = parent.frame()) {
  varname <- as.character(substitute(x))
  if (!exists(varname, envir = envir)) {
    dat <- readr::read_table2(varname, col_names = FALSE)
    assign(varname, dat, envir = envir)
  }
  get(varname, envir = envir)
}
```

Some sample data:

```r
write.table(iris[1:3,], "iris.tab", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
list.files()
# [1] "iris.tab"   "question.R"
```

And its execution:

```r
ls()                       # proof that the data does not yet exist
# [1] "getit"
getit(iris.tab)
# Parsed with column specification:
# cols(
#   X1 = col_double(),
#   X2 = col_double(),
#   X3 = col_double(),
#   X4 = col_double(),
#   X5 = col_character()
# )
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#      X1    X2    X3    X4 X5          
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
# 1   5.1   3.5   1.4   0.2 "\"setosa\""
# 2   4.9   3     1.4   0.2 "\"setosa\""
# 3   4.7   3.2   1.3   0.2 "\"setosa\""
ls()
# [1] "getit"    "iris.tab"
```

It prefers the local copy, not reading from the file if the object exists:

```r
iris.tab[1,1] <- 999
iris.tab
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#      X1    X2    X3    X4 X5          
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
# 1 999     3.5   1.4   0.2 "\"setosa\""
# 2   4.9   3     1.4   0.2 "\"setosa\""
# 3   4.7   3.2   1.3   0.2 "\"setosa\""
getit(iris.tab)
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#      X1    X2    X3    X4 X5          
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
# 1 999     3.5   1.4   0.2 "\"setosa\""
# 2   4.9   3     1.4   0.2 "\"setosa\""
# 3   4.7   3.2   1.3   0.2 "\"setosa\""
readLines("iris.tab")[1]              # file is unchanged
# [1] "5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 \"setosa\""
```

It works even if the file does not exist but the data does:

```r
mt <- mtcars
head(getit(mt))
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
ls()
# [1] "getit"    "iris.tab" "mt"      
list.files()
# [1] "iris.tab"   "question.R"
```

and clearly fails when the object and the data does not exist:

```r
getit(foo.csv)
# Error: 'foo.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/15997184/67753553').
```

(You might choose to `try` to catch that error and elicit something a little more contextual, such as "neither the file nor the object exist ...", over to you.)

Comment: Awesome! That code looks quite a bit nicer than what I had. It still didn't do exactly what I was going for, I got the following to work and it was easy to embed in my larger function:
`getit <- function(x, envir = parent.frame()) {
  varname <- as.character(substitute(x))
  if (!exists(varname, envir = envir)) {
    dat <- readr::read_table2(varname, col_names = FALSE)
    if (class(dat[[1]][[1]]) == "character") {
      rm(dat)
      dat <- readr::read_table2(varname, col_names = TRUE)
    }
    assign(varname, dat, envir = envir)
  }
  get(varname, envir = envir)
}`
Thanks!

Comment: As well, to make this work with the `...` argument called with `morenames<- eval(substitute(alist(...)))` it seems best to add a line after the last `get` something like `morenames[[i]]<-eval(morenames[[i]])` while processing them one at a time in a loop.